Duplicate Entries with same timestamp value in griddb error
can we duplicate timestamp values in a single time-series container? but different readings into GridDB? I have two sensors that generate data simultaneously, each with a unique sensor ID and value, and I want to store this into griddb and facing error.

It seems unlikely that GridDB, or any database for that matter, would allow for duplicate entries. Perhaps the solution lies in creating a separate container for each sensor. You might find more information in the documentation here.
https://griddb.net/en/docs/documents/4-2_data-modeling-using-griddb.php
